# how to solve conflicts between jquery plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a side bar with accordion and I have plugin for it, and I also have plugin for image preview before saving the image in database. Now, the problem is if the plugin for accordion is loaded, the image preview won't work. How should I solve this dilemma? The plugin for sidebar is "js/jquery-2.1.4.js" and "js/main.js".

for my image preview:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadPreview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadPreview.min.js"></script>
<link href="product.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {       
  $.uploadPreview({
    input_field: "#image-upload1",
    preview_box: "#image-preview1",
  });
    $.uploadPreview({
    input_field: "#image-upload2",
    preview_box: "#image-preview2",
  });
  $.uploadPreview({
    input_field: "#image-upload3",
    preview_box: "#image-preview3",
  });
  $.uploadPreview({
    input_field: "#image-upload4",
    preview_box: "#image-preview4",
  });   

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is unclear. Why would you have the non-minimized version and the minimized version loading on the same page? I would pick one. What is the other Script Source?

Comment: the one with image preview is for adding form and the second is the sidebar

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You're loading the same `jquery.uploadPreview` each time.